# How to get the coordinates for an address?

Tags: website, geolocation, coordinates

I'm not necessarily looking for a programmatic way to do this - if I was, I'd ask on Stack Overflow.

I'm just wondering how to quickly retrieve the latitude and longitude for a given address?

Is there a web site that offers this functionality?

Particularly, I'm interested in locations in California.

Comment: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

Comment: Actually with all the proxies and routing stuff, I'm not sure this is even remotely of value these days.

Comment: What is not of value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
[maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com)

An example would be

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Doellgaststrasse+20+86199+Augsburg&sensor=true

The output will be XML, and also could be used with nearly any programming language.